# How do I expand a range between two excel cells in python 3 and add results to a new column?

Tags: python, excel

I would like to use python 3.4 to compare columns.
I have two columns `a` and `b`

- If `A=B` print `A` in column `C`.
- If `B > A`, print all numbers between `A` and `B` including `A` and `B` in column C.

The subsequent compared rows would print in column `C` after the results of the previous test.

Any help is appreciated.  My question wording must be off as I'm sure this has been done before, but I just can't find it here or elsewhere.

Comment: Not sure what you want your output to be, but `df.apply(lambda x: range(x['a'], x['b'] + 1), axis=1)` should give you a good start.

Comment: col a   col b   col c

Comment: So you'll want to read up on how to install `pandas` and how to read an Excel sheet into Python using `pandas`. But once you have that, you can run `df['c'] = df.apply(lambda x: range(x['a'], x['b'] + 1), axis=1)` where `df` is the name of your data.

Answer (score 1):

as [brittenb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2789863/brittenb) noticed, try apply function in pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("somefile.xlsx")
df['c'] = df.apply(lambda r: list(range(r['a'], r['b']+1)), axis=1)
```

## Update

If you want to add rows, writing in pandas may get complicated. If you don't care much about speed and memory, classic python style seems easier to understand.

```
ary = []
for i,r in df.iterrows():
  for j in range(r['a'], r['b']+1):
    ary.append( (r['a'], r['b'], j) )
df = pd.DataFrame(ary, columns = ['a','b','c'])
```

Comment: thank you both, that has expanded the range.  Is there a way to print the results vertically instead of within the same cell?  The results in col c = [4,5,6] bit i would like it as row 1 col c =4, row 2 col c = 5, row 3 col c = 6 etc.

Comment: I thought maybe if I tried str.split or df.stack, but neither are working quite as I had hoped.

Comment: I love you:D.  That is perfect.  Thanks so much

Comment: Here is the final iteration, based on everyone's help.  The idea is to expand ranges between two columns in excel and create a 3rd column of the results.

Comment: nvm it's loo long to fit